# How to override default linux Alt+mouse behaviour when dragging windows?

Tags: c++, linux, wxwidgets

I have a wxWidgets application that has custom controls when pressing Alt+key combo. My problem is that on Linux (ubuntu) when I try to use my controls it doesn't work, but it is using the default Linux controls for window frames.

Can I somehow override the OS custom behaviour with wxWidgets ? Is there some other way to do it ?

Comment: seems like the window manager intercepts these events before you can get them... very common with maya users... http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1182930

Answer (score 0):

If you install dconf-tools you can start dconf-editor and change the key under org - gnome - desktop - wm - preferences - mouse-button-modifier. The safest option is to set it to a key-combination.

Comment: Yes, this is a workaround, but not quite a solution, because people may want to continue using the Linux shortcuts for the rest of the windows, while I want to forbid it for my application only.

Comment: The key combination gets intercepted by the window manager. I don't think you can override that from within an application.